# Using Basic Authentication with IIS Manager Authentication

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7

For a website I would like to add a Basic HTTP 401 Challenge so the visitor will be asked for a username and password before entering the site. Just like in Apache you can use htpasswd and htaccess.

To do so I installed the needed software using these examples:

Installing Basic Authentication: 
https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/basicauthentication

Installing and configuring IIS Manager Authentication: 
http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configure-ftp-with-iis-manager-authentication-in-iis-7

Creating a user in IIS Manager User: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732621%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

And then in IIS Services Manager I went to the website. And changed the settings for the IIS Authentication, setting Basic on Enabled and setting Anonymous to Authentication.

Unfortunately I couldn't login with the user I created. So in IIS Services manager under the Feutures view of the website I allowed the user in IIS Manager Permissions.

But then again it still didn't work.

I did restart the service, but somehow it doesn't seem to work.

Is there anything I still need to do? Is there anything I need to change?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is this a copy of another question or answer?  Or based on another?  If so, please link to the other.  ("0 down vote favorite")

Comment: ha well I somehow had a wrong login. So closed the other one and created this new one. Will edit this